# How avoid pooling data in memory. When iterate cursor object in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How avoid pooling data in memory. When iterate cursor object in pymongo?

Example:

```
def iter():
    c=pymongo.Connection()
    cursor=c.db.media.find().skip(0).limit(50000)
    for item in cursor:
        yield item
```

Before it goes in cycle  `for` there is pause about 2 minus. It loads all data in memory before start iterate for some reason. Can i somehow avoid it?

If I do it in mongodb shell everything is ok.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the cursor (that can be iterated itself) in a generator function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know if this is possible? If c.db.media.find() returns everything instead of an iterator, I'm not sure there's much you can do.

Comment: It does not returns everything. It returns cursor object.

Answer (score 0):

Look at cursor's block_size method. With it you should be able to set how much you read in advance. I say should, because I'm facing some problems with it now ([Getting StopIteration exception on next(cursor) when modifying batch_size in pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984362/getting-stopiteration-exception-on-nextcursor-when-modifying-batch-size-in-pym)), but I'm probably making some mistake. block_size should solve your problem.