# Get a list of documents while iterating through mongodb cursor

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is it possible to retrieve a list of documents while iterating through a mongodb cursor? What I mean by that is:

```
for item in collection.find():
    # do stuff with the document
```

Item is just one document, but could I somehow retrieve a list and continue iterating through the cursor? (because `collection.find()[:2]` returns a list but you don't get to keep your cursor). I know I could use some counter to do that, but is there a syntactic sugar for it?

It looks like cursors can be zipped like lists:

```
for item1, item2 in zip(collection.find(), collection.find({'_id': {'$gt': 0}})):
    print((item1, item2))
```

Edit:
In [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680659/pymongo-cursor-iteration?rq=1) it's shown that you can get the entire collection as a list (if it fits in RAM) and iterate through it. This fits my use case, but what if it doesn't fit in RAM?

Comment: If you find an answer helpful, feel free to upvote and/or accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the rolling-window generators in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6822725/2096752), and apply it to the cursor. E.g.

```
cursor = collection.find()
for doc1, doc2 in window(cursor, n=2):
    print(doc1, doc2)
```

Or

```
for doc1, doc2, doc3 in window(cursor, n=3):
    print(doc1, doc2, doc3)
```

Etc.