# What happens to a pymongo cursor when all its elements have been iterated?

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo

I wanted to use `pymongo` to get an array of entries from my database.  It seems to return a "cursor" instead.  I don't know what that is.

```
    all_nodes = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")["provemath"]["nodes"].find(None)

    print('ALL NODES')
    for node in all_nodes:
        print(node)

    print('STILL NODES')
    for node in all_nodes:
        print(node)
```

There output is:

```
ALL NODES
{'_notes': [], '_examples': [], '_type': 'definition', '_plural': None, '_counterexamples': [], '_intuitions': [], '_id': 'unique', '_importance': 4, '_name': 'unique', '_dependencies': [], '_description': 'An occurence of a property is __unique__ if the property occurs exactly $1$ time.'}
{'_notes': ['Vertices are often drawn as a dot.  They are also called *nodes*.'], '_examples': [], '_type': 'definition', '_plural': '__vertices__', '_counterexamples': [], '_intuitions': [], '_id': 'vertex', '_importance': 4, '_name': 'vertex', '_dependencies': ['unique'], '_description': 'A __vertex__ is a fundamental unit used to create graphs.'}
{'_notes': ['It is possible that $a=b$.'], '_examples': [], '_type': 'definition', '_plural': None, '_counterexamples': [], '_intuitions': ['Edges are usually drawn as a line or curve connecting two vertices.  In the case that $a=b$, the edge is drawn as a small loop that connects $a$ to itself.'], '_id': 'edge', '_importance': 4, '_name': 'edge', '_dependencies': ['unique', 'vertex'], '_description': 'An __edge__ is a set ${a,b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are vertices.'}
{'_notes': [], '_examples': [], '_type': 'definition', '_plural': None, '_counterexamples': [], '_intuitions': [], '_id': 'loop', '_importance': 4, '_name': 'loop', '_dependencies': [], '_description': 'A __loop__ is an edge $e = {a,a} = {a}$.'}
STILL NODES
```

Is a cursor only good for one use? (or is something else going on?)  If I wanted regular array behavior, how would I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Cursor is only good for one use.  As described in [mongodb manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#cursor-behaviors)

> By default, the server will automatically close the cursor after 10
>   minutes of inactivity or if client has exhausted the cursor.

To make you output as python list use

```
node_list = all_nodes[:]
```

or

```
node_list = [node for node in all_nodes]
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680659/pymongo-cursor-iteration)